# build error when integrate apsalar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jenkins

I tried to intergrate apsalar( support.apsalar.com/customer/portal/articles/717507#Proguard)  to my App, after build on jenkins, it return that error

```
20:06:16 :app:compileSha1DeliveredNdk UP-TO-DATE
20:06:16 :app:compileSha1DeliveredSources
20:06:17 :app:proguardSha1Delivered
20:06:17 Warning: com.apsalar.sdk.ApsalarSession: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
20:06:17 Warning: com.apsalar.sdk.ApsalarSession: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
20:06:17 Warning: com.apsalar.sdk.ApsalarSession: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
20:06:17 Warning: com.apsalar.sdk.ApsalarSession: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
20:06:19 Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
20:06:19          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
20:06:19          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
20:06:19          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
20:06:19          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
20:06:19 Exception while processing task 
20:06:19 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
20:06:19    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
20:06:19    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
20:06:19    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
20:06:19    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
20:06:19    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
20:06:19    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
20:06:19    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
20:06:19    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
20:06:19    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
20:06:19    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20:06:32 :app:dexSha1Delivered
20:06:32 :app:validateReleaseSigning
20:06:33 :app:packageSha1Delivered FAILED
```

When build on PC, it was OK but when build on Jenkins it can not build.I don't know why.sorry, some body can help me? thank you very much.